# How can I make side - Navigation menu bar using Angular Mat-Tree?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a JSON  with this structure:

```
    [{
"Standard": "Food",
"Category": [{
        "Name": "Vegetable",
        "Tables": [{
                "Description": "The carrot is a simple root vegetable, usually conical or cylindrical in shape.",
                "Name": "Carrots"
            },
            {
                "Description": " tomatoes come in a wide variety of shapes: round, oblate, pear-shaped, torpedo-shaped,",
                "Name": "Tomatoes"
            }
          ]
    },
    {
    "Name": "Fruits",
    "Tables": [
      {
            "Description": "Oranges",
            "Name": "Spherical shape is of orange"
        },
        {
            "Description": "Grapes",
            "Name": "Grapes are typically an ellipsoid shape resembling a prolate spheroid."
        }]
    }
]
}]
```

And I want to display in this format:

[Format Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IDC3.png)

I have a component : App Component where I have implemented this.
My Component Class: **App.component.ts**

```
import { NestedTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTreeNestedDataSource } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of as observableOf } from 'rxjs';

interface DemoJson {
  Standard: string;
  Category?: category[];
}

interface category {
  Name: string;
  Tables:Descrip[];
}

interface Descrip{
  Description: string;
  Name: string;
}

const TREE_DATA: DemoJson[] = [{
    "Standard": "Food",
    "Category": [{
            "Name": "Vegetable",
            "Tables": [{
                    "Description": "The carrot is a simple root vegetable, usually conical or cylindrical in shape.",
                    "Name": "Carrots"
                },
                {
                    "Description": " tomatoes come in a wide variety of shapes: round, oblate, pear-shaped, torpedo-shaped,",
                    "Name": "Tomatoes"
                }
              ]
        },
        {
        "Name": "Fruits",
        "Tables": [
          {
                "Description": "Oranges",
                "Name": "Spherical shape is of orange"
            },
            {
                "Description": "Grapes",
                "Name": "Grapes are typically an ellipsoid shape resembling a prolate spheroid."
            }]
        }
    ]
}]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<DemoJson>(node => node.Category);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<DemoJson>();

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: DemoJson) => !!node.Category && node.Category.length > 0;

}
```

HTML: **App.component.html**

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
      <li class="mat-tree-node">
      
        <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
        {{node.Standard}}
      </li>
    </mat-tree-node>
  
    <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
      <li>
        <div class="mat-tree-node">
          <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                  [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.Standard">
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
          </button>
          {{node.Name}}
        </div>
        <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
          <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </mat-nested-tree-node>
  </mat-tree>
```

And I keep getting error on this line in **App.component.ts**:

```
treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<DemoJson>(node => node.Category);
```

and the error is:

```
Type 'category[]' is not assignable to type 'DemoJson[] | Observable<DemoJson[]>'.
```

How can I remove this error or Print in desired hierarchical structure.

Answer (score 0):

This normaly says the fact that your object `models/interfaces` are not matching. You are trying to assign `DemoJson[]` type to `category[]` type. In order to avoid this try using :

`treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<any>(node => node.Category);`

Please refer to the sample `MatTree` view implementation below:

> Working stackblitz link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tree-test-simple-g2bf1m?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Sample HTML :**

```
<h1>MatTreeTest</h1>

    <mat-tree [dataSource]="properDataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
      <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
        <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
        <div>
        {{node.prop}}
        </div>
      </mat-tree-node>
    
    
      <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle>
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>
        {{node.prop}}
    
        <!-- This part wasn't in yours at all, its how you show nested 
            children on the control. -->
        <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
            <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
        </ul>
      </mat-nested-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
```

**Sample component.ts :**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "./data.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { NestedTreeControl } from "@angular/cdk/tree";
import { MatTreeNestedDataSource } from "@angular/material/tree";

/**
 * Just created a type to repreasent your data
 * with an optional children array
 */
interface PropData {
  prop: string;
  children?: PropData[];
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  getChildren = node => {
    return this.data.getData();
  };

  // The data source needs to be an actual data source type.  Below
  // I used a MatTreeNestedDataSource as properDataSource.  That is
  // what is actually attached to the template.  This I just left in
  // for comparison
  dataSource: any[];
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<PropData>(node => node.children);

  topLevelData: PropData[] = [
    {
      prop: "people",
      children: [
        { prop: "foo5" },
        { prop: "foo6" },
        { prop: "foo7" },
        { prop: "foo8" }
      ]
    },
    {
      prop: "people again",
      children: [{ prop: "foo0" }, { prop: "foo1" }, { prop: "foo2" }]
    }
  ];

  properDataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<PropData>();

  constructor(private data: DataService) {
    this.dataSource = this.topLevelData;

    // No need to explicitly connect the treeControl here, it is
    // already bound to the component in the template.  Instead here
    // I'm just setting the data itself.
    this.properDataSource.data = this.topLevelData;
  }

  // Rewritten slightly based on the interface I created.
  hasChild = (_: number, node: PropData) =>
    !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Now, Error is removed but nothing is getting displayed according to the format which I have shown in the picture.

Comment: Yes I JSON is not acctually an Iteratebale array. Thats the issue. I will provide you with sample implementations of tree implmentation Will you be able refactor it accordingly to yours? Also appreciate if you can mark this answer as correct. SInce it has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the menu is basic static, there is no point if you can't navigate using it, Consider routing using routerLink and then you will encounter one other problem that is if you have nested menu items then a similar thing like event propagation takes place.
I am encountering that problem by the way.
When I will solve that, will surely post and answer with stackBlitz code. Thanks.